# Upload via to Blob Storage using Rest API with Shared Access Signature

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use the Put Blob Rest API from Postman (at the moment) using also a code generated SAS.
If I set the body as binary in postman and I select my file everything works just fine - I get my file in the blob storage as expected.
However, if I send the file using a multipart/form-data the file is being uploaded, but I get additional data at the beginning of the file such as:

`----------------------------515848534032814231487294
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="my_file.json"
Content-Type: application/json`

Does anybody know why is that and how I could use multipart/form-data for uploading my file to the blob storage?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior when using `multipart/form-data`.

By using `multipart/form-data`, the boundary(like this `---515848534032814231487294`) is auto-generated in the file. But the `blob storage backend` does not get rid of it(means remove these lines auto-generated).

And one more thing, `multipart/form-data` is mostly used in a web project, and you can write a function which is used to processing these extra lines in the backend.

Comment: I'm already having a few clients (mobile and desktop apps) that currently upload files to a Google Bucket by doing a POST and using a multipart/form-data for the file. I want to switch to Azure blob storage and keep the clients untouched if possible (for switching the method from POST to PUT and setting the blob storage specific headers I'm using the Api Management layer) - which seems to work fine so far...

Comment: @AndreiC,for google Bucket, I think it supports auto-parse it in the background. But for blob storage, it does not support it in background. But anyway, I will check it with the storage team, and update you if any feedback.

Comment: @AndreiC, I just confirmed with storage team, the reason is that azure storage will not change or add some content to the blob file. So when use `multipart/form-data` via `postman`(or other tools like `Insomnia rest client`), by default the tool will add these kinds of boundary; when it uploaded to azure storage, azure storage keeps the format. Hope this can help you.

Comment: and the blob storage is usually used for binary data, so you'd better select binary instead of multipart/form-data.